# Setting the DialogResult property on nested Forms showed modally causes the hiding of the modal dialogs to propagate back in the forms tree

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

I've two nested Forms (form1 and form2) showed modally, i.e. from my MainForm I show the form1 modally by calling (on a button click event) `form1.ShowDialog()` and from the code of form1 I then call (on another button click event) `form2.ShowDialog()`.

By setting the DialogResult property of the form2 (e.g. by clicking the X close button on the form title bar), the form2 is hidden (as expected) but also the form1 is hidden (unexpectedly). The main thread executes the code after the `form2.ShowDialog()` line and, immediately after, keeps on executing the code after the `form1.ShowDialog()` line.

I tried out the same nested pattern with a new project and it came out that the hiding is not propagated to the first calling form. Hence there must be something wrong with my code, but I cannot find it. Anyone knows what could cause this?

---

If this can help, I've also stopped both projects in debug mode immediately after clicking the close button of the form2. The Call Stacks of both projects are exactly the same from the call to the Program.Main() on. The Call Stacks only differ before this call. I try to highlight the differences:

**Not working project**

```
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly assembly, string[] args) + 0x9 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(bool checkAptModel) + 0x6e bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly() + 0x90 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(System.ActivationContext activationContext, string[] activationCustomData) + 0x65 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(System.ActivationContext activationContext) + 0xd bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.ActivationContext activationContext) + 0x44 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone() + 0x23 bytes
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x63 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x2c bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes   
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

**Working project**

```
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x6d bytes    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x2a bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x63 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x2c bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

**EDIT**
Here instead is how I open the forms:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form2 form2 = new Form2())
    {
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code showing how you open the forms?

Comment: thanks for posting the code to open form2 but what about form1? do you have an form closing events, etc?

Comment: @bluefeet form1 is showed in the same way on the click event of a button belonging to my MainForm. No, I've no closing or any other events neither in form1 nor in form2

Comment: it seems like something is missing with the code, I just tried your code with a mainform, and two additional forms opened with your code and it works fine for me.  form1 is not getting hidden when I close form2

Comment: @bluefeet thanks for your efforts. I tried too with another project and everything works. There must be something for sure but I cannot neither figure out how to find it. Maybe is something stupid or maybe is some project setting. I've no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine that the button1 control on Form1 has the DialogResult property set to something other than `DialogResult.None`.

Comment: Actually the DialogResult property was not set. But after reading your post I manually set the property to 'DialogResult.None' and now the problem is solved! This is really weird however since I've searched for all the references to DialogResult and there were not. Hence I still do not understand where the problem was but at least there is a simple way to avoid it.

Comment: Your reply is not 100% correct but helped me a lot to find a solution. What should I do, should I accept it?

Comment: @Ganswer. In my experience, the form will only close automatically if either (a) form2.DialogResult is set programatically to something other than None, or (b) button1.DialogResult is set to something other than None.  When you say "the DialogResult property was not set", do you mean form2.DialogResult or button1.DialogResult?  If you're interested enough you should carefully compare the code in your new (working) project with that in your existing project.  It's up to you to decide whether this answer should be accepted.

Comment: Ok I found the stupid error. As you were imaging it was the button1.DialogResult property. The automatic generated code from Windows Form Designer set the property to Cancel when time ago I chose that button as the CancelButton from the form1 Properties. Later on when I set back again from the designer the CancelButton for the form1 to "(none)", the line of code setting the button1.DialogResult property was not automatically deleted. I was able to reproduce the same behaviour also in the test project.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suppose that your form1 has the CancelButton or AcceptButton property set to button1

Comment: They were set but I've already removed both properties and nothing changes